# weird thing in C: not zero is not equal to one

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int a = 2147483647; 
    int c = a + a + 2;
    printf("2a + 2 = %d, !(2a + 2) = %d, !c = %d\n", (2 * a + 2), !(a + a + 2), !c);
}
```

I got this when I run those codes above

> 2a + 2 = 0, !(2a + 2) = 0, !c = 1

a is Tmax which in binary form is 0111...111, so a + a + 2 is suposed to be 0000...0000.
I don't understand why !(2a + 2) is not equal to 1 when (2a + 2) is actually 0, but !c is 1!!!
Please help me

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior.

Comment: @interjay
thanks for help! But I don't get the meaning of undefined behavior. Do you mean that a + a + 2 can be a non-zero value?

Comment: Undefined behaviour means there's no definition for the outcome, so when you ask whether "Do you mean", then there's no correct answer as there's no formal definition of what the operation should do.

Comment: @Matthew
Thanks! Finally I get it!

Comment: @phuclv
Thank you for you link, I understand what is going on here~~~

Comment: Not sure this is a dup.  The question is more about the nature of undefined behavior rather than unsigned vs signed wraparound.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming an `int` is 32 bits, the operations you're performing cause signed integer overflow.  Doing so triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  It does *not* necessarily wraparound.

In fact, this specific case is given as an example of undefined behavior in section 3.4.3p3 of the [C standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) where the term *undefined behavior* is defined:

> An example of undefined behavior is the behavior on integer overflow

You've encountered one of the stranger ways that undefined behavior can manifest itself, where seemingly identical operations behave differently.  Undefined behavior means that no guarantees are made about what your program will do.

Comment: You can not imagine how desprate I am when I saw this output came out